# How to set TCP_KEEPINTVL in C# using System.Net.Sockets.Socket

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient, .net-7.0

I would like to set `TCP_KEEPIDLE`, `TCP_KEEPINTVL`, and `TCP_KEEPCNT` settings using C# .NET Standard 2.1  `System.Net.Sockets.Socket` class in C# (that is accessed by `TcpClient.Client`).

`Socket.SetRawSocketOption()` doesn't seem to exist in .NET Standard 2.1. And, `Socket.SetSocketOption` doesn't seem to have the ability to set these options.

Can these be set using `Socket.IOControl`? If so how? If not, how can I set these values?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Net library does not have all Network option built into the library and because it is managed you cannot get around the issue.  The two solutions is to use c++ for these features or use a Pinvoke connection for these options.  See www.pinvoke.net

Comment: It's right there: `SocketOptionName.TcpKeepAliveInterval` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socketoptionname?view=net-8.0 If .NET Standard doesnn't have it then maybe just force it by casting from `int` like this `(SocketOptionName) 17`

Comment: Note that the `TCP_KEEP[IDLE|INTVL|CNT]` socket options don't exist on Windows, only on 'Nix. The Windows equivalent is to use [`WSAIoctl()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsaioctl) instead with the [`SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/sio-keepalive-vals) control code.